# Populating table cells with unique data - qa automation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, cypress, ui-automation

I have a table that looks like this -

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  ...
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

The data in each cell is populated with a unique value from a json object, or a unique action takes place on it (ie check mark).
The difficulty comes when a user can add additional rows with the same column count.
How do I write an algorithm/function that will go through each cell and populate it with my unique json values or perform a specific action?

This is for Cypress QA Automation (Js/Ts). Each cell has a unique locator, but if I go that way, my page object model will have duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fetching the data from a server, you'll have to build the table every time the data is fetched using a JavaScript function. I found an article that might be helpful: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/creating-a-dynamic-html-table-through-javascript-f554fba376cf.